# Prevent Update on Contact/Lead with Specific Email

Tags: gdpr

When updating contacts/leads I'd like to be able to check against a list of 10 (and growing) emails. If the record being updated/created matches one of the emails on the list, I want to throw a validation error e.g. "Person is blacklisted".

My initial thought was to just have a large validation rule on the Contact and Lead objects that checks the whole list of emails in the rule criteria i.e. `OR(CONTAINS(email,"dave@gmail.com"),CONTAINS(email,"dave1@gmail.com"),etc.,etc.`

However, the list of emails grows by about 1 a month, and I want to avoid having to iterate this formula every time I want to add an email to the list.

How can I check a Contact/Lead record updates against a list of emails in a more efficient way? Queues?

P.S. I've had the Individual object suggested to me, but its functionality is limited, also, I don't believe it's necessary as my email list size is about **10** right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the list of emails in another object and then have a trigger on your Contact and Lead object that does a check against this list.

High level code:

```
trigger myContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update)
{

    BlackList__c[] recs = [Select Email__c From BlackList__c];
    Set<String> emls = new Set<String>();

    for(BlackList__c r : recs)
    {
        emls.add(r.Email__c)
    }

    for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(emls.contains(c.Email))
        {
            c.addError('This is a Blacklisted Email');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would love to implement if I had more knowledge of triggers. How many lines would it be approximately?

Comment: @Nivi I have updated my answer to be a working example

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link to any documentation about how to implement in org? I want to try this solution.

Comment: Not specifically, this is a valid trigger. The only thing you would have to implement would be a custom object called `BlackList__c`